# packages.config is missing in visual stiudio 2017 Web Application

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2017

After creating new Web Application and adding a **NuGet** dependencies.

Figured that the `packages.config` file is missing. The application is working perfectly. How does dependencies get linked to the project in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mendtioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files), `packages.config` file is no longer needed. The dependencies references is included in the **.NET Core project files**.

**csproj xml:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff">
        <Version>3.6.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```